# How to force usage of Try/Catch around specific methods

Tags: c#, exception, attributes, try-catch

I am creating a "Common" library to be used as reference in various solution projects by other team members. The methods are typically `void` functions with no actual returned data.

I am looking for a why to force the usage of these methods within a `Try...Catch` block by others. I need to make sure errors are properly handled. I though about relying on a Boolean return type but that will not allow me to return the error message as well, so my only option is throwing an `Exception`.

If proper forcing is not possible, how can I make an attribute that pops-up when compiling to warn the developer about the Try/Catch requirement? (sort of the `Obsolete` attribute).

Any other better approaches?

**EDIT:**

Here is my full scenario:

I have a code method calling a web service to update a value remotely. The update is quite crucial. The method it self works fine but what if the web service is not reachable? The call does not return any value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Placing something inside a `try`/`catch` block does not make it "properly handled" - in fact, in the **vast majority** of cases, the correct way of handling an exception is to let it bubble up to the next level. Caveat: `try`/`finally` is much more common, to allow for resource clean-up, but even more common than that is `using`.

You cannot enforce "and you must use it correctly" on code; that is implicit in any API, and you will just be causing irritation and annoyance, and forcing people into inappropriate and unhelpful coding styles, while giving you a **completely artificial and incorrect** sense of the code being correct.

If you want to be sure that the code functions correctly: test it.

There are no attributes that you can use for this scenario. You can probably create an FxCop rule or similar, but for the reasons above: I do not recommend it.

Comment: I agree, but I could give you a counter example. I have a method which is calling a web service to update a value. The method it self works fine. There is no return type. What if the web service is not reachable? (knowing that the update is quite crucial)

Comment: @Moslem, then you have a BIG problem, and a try/catch around the proximate caller of that method is not going to help any.  Best to do as Marc suggests and let it bubble up to a place where it can actually be handled correctly (and either logged, shown to the user, or both).

Comment: @MoslemBenDhaou then indeed, it is expected that there will be an exception; but the fact that the update is quite crucial is a feature of that calling code, and an appropriate strategy (rollback, retry, whatever) needs to be devised. This is not done simply by creating a `try`/`catch`, and is suitably complicated that it should be tested

Comment: That is exactly what is being done currently, and unfortunately it is bubbled up to the end user. (not handled at all). I am just looking for a way to make sure it is handled somewhere

Comment: @MoslemBenDhaou simply checking for a `try`/`catch` doesn't satisfy what you actually want to achieve, hence there is no benefit in checking for it...

Comment: humm.. I though that it might help creating the "good will" annoyance as you mentioned :/

Comment: @MoslemBenDhaou if people need to add a `try`/`catch` just to get the code to compile, then ***they will add a `try`/`catch` just to get the code to compile***; what you want to check is that they are actually doing something sensible - this is much harder to enforce

Comment: Unfortunately that is true. I Agree. :/ I guess I need to look for a way how to change people coding attitude not my code. :)

Comment: @MarcGravell I disagree that forcing {try} would bring no benefit. I just ran into the exact same issue as the OP. A common lib that offers classes where operations can fail due to network. Java enforces {try} so at least the user consuming your API is aware that there is the possibility that it would fail. If he cannot handle, then he just bubble it up. One could argue that this is a documentation problem. Indeed... As returning (or not) "null" is as well. But then notice how C# team saw that, and added reference null check now, which is a similar situation as we are discussing here.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't actually do this, but as a fun solution to the stated problem you could build your own Exception type: a SuccessException. Then, you throw this exception at the end of your method to indicate success. This makes the method pretty much unusable without some form of try/catch. But, again: *don't do this.*

Comment: But pls don't do that:)

Comment: very funny :) The issue is not with throwing an exception :) it is with making sure it is handled.

Answer (score 0):

You could return a custom result class:

```
public class Result
{
    public bool Okay { get; set; }
    public string Error { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
var result = AttemptSomething();

if (!result.Okay)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result.Error);
}
```

---

Or maybe return `string`:

```
var error = AttemptSomething();

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
{
    Console.WriteLine(error);
}
```

---

Or have the error as an out:

```
string error;
if (!AttemptSomething(out error))
{
    Console.WriteLine(error);
}
```

---

Or return `Exception` but *don't* throw.